# Why initialize a Python variable to None before giving it a real value later?

Tags: python, rospy

That is, what's the value of `pub = None` in the below? When and why is this a good practice?

```
counter = 0
pub = None

def callback_receive_number_data(msg):
    global counter
    counter += msg.data
    new_msg = Int64()
    new_msg.data = counter
    pub.publish(new_msg)

sub = rospy.Subscriber('/number', Int64, callback_receive_number_data)
pub = rospy.Publisher('/number_count', Int64, queue_size=10)
```

Comment: BTW, when editing, please ensure that your code is still formatted... well... *as code*. That means either triple-backticks on their own lines before starting and ending a multi-line code segment, or four-space indents on all lines that should be code-formatted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy off-topic, but 35k reputation later and I didn't know SO allowed github-style triple-backquotes to demarcate code blocks. Sheesh.

Comment: @AdamSmith, that's a quite new feature -- for many years they didn't work, so it's forgivable. :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I have 10x as much, and I didn't know about them until recently. They seem to have become extramely popular in the past week.

Comment: @AdamSmith https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/397555

Answer (score 2):

Googling parts of the code brought me to [this page](https://roboticsbackend.com/oop-with-ros-in-python/) which breaks down each line of code.

Specific to the section in question above, the site states:

> We initialize a global counter as well as a publisher. If we want to
> use them in all the functions of the program, we have to declare them
> in the global scope, which is far from optimal. We’ll see later that
> OOP code will solve that problem.

So, in short, it's a way to declare a variable without assigning anything to it. If it were a string, you could declare it like `some_string = ""` but because `pub` is a 'publisher' this is just an easier way to declare it for later use in the code.

Comment: Okay, but given the `pub = rospy....` later the `pub = None` still seems kind of pointless. Even if the callback is called before `pub` is redefined, the call to the method of `pub` would fail for `pub = None`.

Comment: if pub = None, why does pub.publish(msg) still work in the callback?

Comment: I think the hope is that `pub` will have been set to something else before the callback is called, therefore the callback will never see `pub` as `None`

Answer (score 1):

I mostly do it so that my IDE doesn't yell at me that the variable could be undeclared. In the example above, if you didn't have the `pub = None` line, some editors, in an effort to be smart, will highlight the line `pub.publish(new_msg)` and say "pub might not be declared!" or something like that. It's not a problem as long as, in the runtime, `pub` will exist before that function is called. An editor can't figure that out just by looking at your code (not easily, at least), so to avoid the warning it's easier just to make sure `pub` exists in the namespace before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The `pub = None` line is not needed. It *could* be useful, but with the rest of the code as written, it is not.

The issue is that you're writing a function that expects there to be a global variable `pub` which it will call certain methods on. That code will fail if `pub` is undefined. Unfortunately it will *also* fail if `pub` is `None` (just in a different way).

Now, that's probably not a problem as long as the function isn't called before `pub` gets a real value. But in this code, the function *does* get passed as a callback to `rospy.Subscriber` before `pub` is reassigned, so (without knowing anything about `rospy`) it might theoretically get called immediately, before the next line on the top level runs, giving `pub` a real value.

There are a few ways that things could be better. First, you could define `pub` before doing *anything* with `callback_receive_number_data`. Consider just swapping the order of the last two lines, so that `pub` is defined first, then `sub` (with the function as its callback).

Second, you could add error handling code to the callback function to detect when `pub` isn't yet defined. This would let the function behave in a controlled way if there is no appropriate value in `pub`. For this approach, the `pub = None` assignment would be helpful, as it's easier to detect a bad value in a variable than when the variable is completely missing. But this approach might also suppress real bugs, so I'd only go for it if you are sure there is a good way to handle errors in every situation (rather than crashing with a traceback that will hopefully point out a bug to the programmer).

Comment: no. the code works as is...that's what I don't understand.

Comment: That just means that the `Subscriber` object you create doesn't immediately call its callback function. Once `pub` is defined, then the `pub = None` line doesn't matter any more, since the variable it created has been overwritten. My point is that it didn't help any, not that it did any harm.